# SQL: Nested Condition in Case When Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, case-when

I have a `Case-When` clause like this;

```
(CASE WHEN A.YAZ_ADRES IS NULL
         THEN (B.IS_ADRES1 +' '+B.IS_ADRES2) 
         ELSE A.YAZ_ADRES END)
```

I want to use a condition after `THEN`

For Example;

```
(CASE WHEN A.YAZ_ADRES IS NULL
         THEN (IF B.TUZ = 'T' THEN (B.IS_ADRES1 +' '+B.IS_ADRES2) ELSE ((B.EV_ADRES1 +' '+B.EV_ADRES2)))
         ELSE A.YAZ_ADRES END)
```

How can I use nested condition in `Case-When` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest `CASE` clauses like this:

```
(CASE WHEN A.YAZ_ADRES IS NULL
  THEN
    (CASE WHEN B.TUZ = 'T'
      THEN (B.IS_ADRES1 +' '+B.IS_ADRES2)
      ELSE ((B.EV_ADRES1 +' '+B.EV_ADRES2))
    END)
  ELSE A.YAZ_ADRES
END)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... (WHEN ... THEN ...)+ ELSE ... END`. It returns the `THEN` expression of the *first* matching `WHEN` condition:

```
CASE WHEN A.YAZ_ADRES IS NULL AND B.TUZ = 'T'
       THEN B.IS_ADRES1 +' '+B.IS_ADRES2
     WHEN A.YAZ_ADRES IS NULL 
       THEN B.EV_ADRES1 +' '+B.EV_ADRES2
     ELSE A.YAZ_ADRES
END
```

Comment: Nice advice (about `CASE` stopping at the first matching `WHEN` condition), but with the nested `CASE` you avoid repeating the `A.YAZ_ADRES IS NULL` condition.

Answer (score 3):

Nest another `CASE` instead of an `IF`

Comment: Thanks. Can't I use IF condition? Always would be Case ?

Answer (score 1):

```
(CASE WHEN A.YAZ_ADRES IS NULL          
  THEN (CASE WHEN B.TUZ = 'T' THEN (B.IS_ADRES1 +' '+B.IS_ADRES2) ELSE ((B.EV_ADRES1 +' '+B.EV_ADRES2)) END)          
ELSE A.YAZ_ADRES END)
```